# Not able to install NUnit 3 test adapter in Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition

Tags: unit-testing, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-2013, nunit, nunit-3.0

I am starting to work on the Selenium Webdriver in C# using NUnit Framework. I watched a lot of videos for the best installation and configuration steps so that I don't need to bother much about checkin of everything into TFS. I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional edition and .NET Framework 4.5. Below are the steps that I followed till now:

1. Created a new Unit test project in Visual Studio 2013.
2. By default, [TestClass] and [TestMethod] annotations got created and default using statement was present for Visual Studio Unit testing framework, but since I want to use NUnit framework I removed these two annotations.
3. I installed Selenium webdriver (version 3.0.1) by right clicking on the solution -> Manage NuGet packages for the solution option.
4. Installed NUnit (3.5.0) in the same way from Manage NuGet packages option
5. Tried to install the NUnit Test adapter from menu *Tools* → *Extensions and updates* → *Online* → searched for NUnit test adapter. Only one option, "NUnit Test Adapter", (version 2.0.0) is visible which is not correct. Ideally I should also see "NUnit3 Test Adapter" in the search result.
6. I tried to do install locally the latest version of NUnit package, but even that is not getting installed.

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you done the online search for NUnit3 Test Adapter? It's actually a different package, not just an upgrade.

Comment: Yes I did that too. But I am not getting how to integrate it with my VS2013. I downloaded NUnit 3.4.1 from the official website but not able to install it. It gives me errors.